# Multiple columns in container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am learning Flutter, I want to achieve this look: [image]

Does Container only allow one child? I want to have multiple of columns, like on the picture I will need 3 for logo, text box and for two buttons. How do I set this up properly? Maybe I should not use container?

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("test"),
          Text("test")
        ]
      )
```

Also, what does this code do?
`const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);` I haven't seen that in any of the tutorials. is that some sort of constructor?

Comment: You asked multiple questions in that post. 1) Container only allows one Child, if you need multiple then use Column, Row, Stack etc. 2) That's a constructor. Now probably you need to check about Keys to understand what's the meaning of that constructor and why that's used

Comment: @MidhunMP there is too many options.. how do I know which one Im supposed to use?

Comment: Each widget has it's own behavior, so you are the one supposed to find which one is suitable for your need. You can check the corresponding documentation to understand the behavior. Example: Column widgets renders it's children vertically and Row renders horizontally, Using stack you can put a widget on top of another etc. So In this case, you can check Column widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the top `logo` part, you can simply use `appBar` of `Scaffold`.

Next comes the large box `TextBox`, you can use `Expanded` with `Align` widget inside column for this.

While we used `Expanded` it will take available height.
Therefore next two button will be at the bottom side.

I will suggest visiting and learn more about [widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets), there are many ways you can handle this UI. You can search and read about every widget.

```dart
class TX extends StatelessWidget {
  const TX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Text("logo"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                child: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, .5),
                  child: Text("TextBox"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button"),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Buttonx"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And for the key constructor already describe on comments by @Midhun MP. It is used to identify the widget tree. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)

Answer (score 0):

> Does Container only allow one child?

Yes, `Container()` can only have one child widget.

Widgets are like lego blocks. You have to pick a widget that best suits your requirements. For Showing widgets in a single column, You can use `Column()` Widget. Similarly in case of row, You can represent widgets in single Row using `Row()` Widget. Similarly for stacking of widgets, use `Stack()` widget. This list goes on just like the availablility of lego blocks.

Now back to your implementation, you are going the right way. You don't need Container() at the top, Just add 4 child widgets in Column.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Image(),
    TextField(),
    TextButton(),
    TextButton(),
  ],
)
```

Study about the available customization options of these widgets and you will be able to implement this UI as per your requirements.

P.S. There are many type of buttons available in flutter. If `TextButton()` doesn't work for you, you can pick any other button.